# Friend function template with automatic return type deduction cannot access a private member

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, friend

*Sorry for how complicated the title of this question is; I tried to describe the minimal SSCCE I constructed for this problem.*

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace fizz
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    class bar
    {
    public:
        template<int I, typename... Us>
        friend auto foo(const bar<Us...> &);

    private:
        int i = 123;
    };

    template<int I, typename... Ts>
    auto foo(const bar<Ts...> & b)
    {
        return b.i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fizz::foo<1>(fizz::bar<int, float>{});
}
```

This code [compiles with GCC 5.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d45c79e8f9ba902) and [doesn't with Clang 3.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9735ebd213a4840):

```
main.cpp:19:18: error: 'i' is a private member of 'fizz::bar<int, float>'
        return b.i;
                 ^
main.cpp:25:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fizz::foo<1, int, float>' requested here
    std::cout << fizz::foo<1>(fizz::bar<int, float>{});
                       ^
main.cpp:13:13: note: declared private here
        int i = 123;
            ^
```

However, if you change the code slightly (although in a way that is not exactly useful for me, since in the real code this would introduce tons of boilerplate):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace fizz
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    class bar
    {
    public:
        template<int I, typename... Us>
        friend int foo(const bar<Us...> &);

    private:
        int i = 123;
    };

    template<int I, typename... Ts>
    int foo(const bar<Ts...> & b)
    {
        return b.i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fizz::foo<1>(fizz::bar<int, float>{});
}
```

it suddenly [works with that Clang 3.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f2b259d0fc6d494).

The difference is that in the version of the code that doesn't compile with Clang, the friend function template uses C++14 `auto` return type deduction, while the working one plainly says it returns `int`. The same problem also happens with other variants of `auto` return type deduction, like `auto &&` or `const auto &`.

Which compiler is right? Please provide some standard quotes to support the answer, since it is quite possible that a bug will need to be filed for one (...hopefully not both) compilers... or a standard defect, if both are right (which wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: I am surprised.  I figured the friend function in the class would be unrelated to the function outside without declaring the function outside the class *before* the friend.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case.  Hmm.  In practice, would a `->decltype` be a doable workaround?

Comment: @Yakk A `friend` declaration *can* declare a function in the innermost enclosing namespace. I don't think `auto` is special here and suspect this is a clang bug, but can't come up with a good set of wordings to support that.

Comment: If you drop the `int I` template argument, and make an unqualified call to `foo()`, clang reports the call as ambiguous... so for some reason it does think there are two separate function template `foo`s.

Comment: I thought it introduced it, but for some reason thought it would be distinct unless the 'outer' one was introduced first.  I do not know why I thought that.

Comment: Aha!  Because inline definition friends do follow that rule: [class.friend]/7 -- friend functions that are not inline are in the lexical scope of the enclosing namespace.  (that is why I had that misunderstanding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's a clang bug. I want to approach it from this direction. What wrinkles does the `auto` placeholder type add, as compared to having a specified return type? From [dcl.spec.auto]:

> The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the *decl-specifier-seq*, *type-specifier-seq*, *conversion-function-id*, or *trailing-return-type*, in any context where such a declarator is valid. If the function declarator includes a *trailing-return-type* (8.3.5), that *trailing-return-type* specifies the declared return type
>   of the function. Otherwise, the function declarator shall declare a function. If the declared return type of
>   the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from return statements
>   in the body of the function, if any.

`auto` can appear in `foo`'s declaration and definition, and is valid.

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression,
>   the program is ill-formed. Once a `return` statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type
>   deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> auto n = n;              // error, n’s type is unknown
> auto f();
> void g() { &f; }         // error, f’s return type is unknown
> auto sum(int i) {
>   if (i == 1)
>     return i;            // sum’s return type is int
>   else
>     return sum(i-1)+i;   // OK, sum’s return type has been deduced
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The first time we need to use determine the type of an expression, the return type of the function will already have been deduced from the `return` in the definition of `foo()`, so this is still valid.

> Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a
>   placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type.

We're using `auto` in both places, so we don't violate this rule either.

---

In short, there are several things that differentiate a specific return type from an placeholder return type from a function declaration. But all the usages of `auto` in the example are correct, so the namespace-scope `foo` should be seen as a redeclaration and definition of the first-declared `friend auto foo` within class template `bar`. The fact that clang accepts the former as a redeclaration for return type `int` but not for `auto`, and there is no relevant different for `auto`, definitely suggests this is a bug.

Further, if you drop the `int I` template parameter so that you can call `foo` unqualified, clang will report the call as ambiguous:

```
std::cout << foo(fizz::bar<int, float>{});

main.cpp:26:18: error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    std::cout << foo(fizz::bar<int, float>{});
                 ^~~
main.cpp:10:21: note: candidate function [with Us = <int, float>]
        friend auto foo(const bar<Us...> &);
                    ^
main.cpp:17:10: note: candidate function [with Ts = <int, float>]
    auto foo(const bar<Ts...>& b)
         ^
```

So we have *two* function templates named `foo` in the same namespace (since from [namespace.memdef] the `friend` declaration for `foo` will place it in the nearest enclosing namespace) that take the same arguments and have the same return type (`auto`)? That shouldn't be possible.

Comment: There is definitely a clang bug: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90ad356e8a27fbbd It seems to declare another function via the friend-declaration even though that declaration uses a qualified-id.

Comment: Oh - so the actual bug would be actually *hidden* by the additional template introduced to reproduce the original problem? That's interesting. But this is also - I think - good, since this is a bug that'll probably be easier to track by Clang devs.

Comment: @Griwes I don't think it's hidden, just another example. In your original case, clang still makes two separate `foo`s. The `friend`ed one isn't callable qualified, so it unambiguously calls the non-`friend`ed one.

Comment: @Barry: yes, but the exact cause for why the member is not accessible is not entirely visible in the original SSCCE; you can only tell that the function can't access the member, but it isn't clear that there are actually two functions being created by the compiler.

Comment: Why does dropping the first template parameter change the error?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your first example should work.  There is a statement in C++14 (7.1.6.4 p12):

> Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a
>   placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type. [ Example:

.
.
.

```
template <typename T> struct A {
    friend T frf(T);
};
auto frf(int i) { return i; } // not a friend of A<int>
```

The reason for the example appears to be to explain that to make the declarations match (and cause the defined function to be a friend) the declaration of frf inside struct A would also need to use `auto`.  This implies to me that having a friend declaration with an auto return type and later defining the friend function (and also using auto) is allowed.  I can't find anything that would make this work differently for a member function template, like in your example.